# Why is my Index Match generating an error? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Am I performing the Index Match function in the wrong location?
Should I even be using IndexMatch?
My information in the table I am trying to get the information out of has CO number in column A.
Columns B has the information I am trying to populate my new worksheet with.

```
Sub AddWorkbooks()

Dim ChangeOrder As Range
Dim XCXX As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CoForm As Worksheet
Dim CoFormCopy As Worksheet

Dim srNO As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set XCXX = ActiveSheet
Set CoForm = wb.Worksheets("+CO Form+")
'Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
srNO = XCXX.Range("D2").Value

'CoForm.Copy After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index)
CoForm.Copy After:=XCXX
ActiveSheet.Name = "Proj" & " " & XCXX.Range("D2").Value

Set CoFormCopy = XCXX.Next 'the copy of +CO Form

With CoFormCopy
    
    
    'Adds CO Number
    Range("A6:D6").Value = XCXX.Range("D2").Value
    'Adds CO Description from CO_List sheet based on CO Number
    Range("A16").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("CO_List").Range("B3:B"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(srNO, Sheets("CO_List").Range("A3:A"), 0))
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = XCXX.Range("D2").Value
     
End With

CoFormCopy.Move
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B3:B")` is invalid. Either write `Range("B:B")` for the entire column or specify the end cell, eg `Range("B3:B100")`.

Comment: It's also possible to use `Range.Cells()` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index()`, and `Range.Find()` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()`

Comment: Youe have `With CoFormCopy` but no dot on `Range("A6:D6").Value` so it will default to the active sheet not CoFormCopy.

Answer (score 0):

If no match is found `WorksheetFunction.Match` will fail. `Application.Match` will return #N/A error that you can test for with `IsError()`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddWorkbooks()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim srNo, desc As String
    Dim v, lastrow As Long
    
    ' project number
    srNo = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value
    
    ' find desc from CO_List sheet based on CO Number
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb.Sheets("CO_List")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        v = Application.Match(srNo, .Range("A3:A" & lastrow), 0)
        If IsError(v) Then
           MsgBox "No Description for '" & srNo & "'", vbExclamation
           desc = "Description for " & srNo
        Else
           desc = Application.Index(.Range("B3:B" & lastrow), v)
        End If
    End With
  
    ' create new workbbok
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With wbNew.Sheets(1)
        .Name = "Proj" & " " & srNo
        .Range("A6:D6").Value = srNo
        .Range("A16") = desc
    End With
    MsgBox "New workbook created for " & srNo, vbInformation
    
    'wbNew.Save
    
End Sub
```